# Correlation in space (influence of building function on number of people passing through some point)

Tags: correlation, spatial

I am in a need of solving such problem: I have two data sets: number of people passing nearby some point in space (two points were analysed) and the function of buildings around those points. How do I find the correlation (or test if influence exists) of building functions to number of people passing by. For example:

The drawing below shows idealized situation. Color of the rectangle denotes building function (Bank, bakery etc.). In the middle of those two building groups (crossroads) number of passers by was counted. How to check if building functions influence people's choice of road crossing point?

[image]

Comment: Can you be more clear about where passers by are counted? Is it cars that travel though the street segment (in between the crossroad)? Or is it where pedestrians actual cross the street (at multiple points or just within the street segment)?

Comment: Pedestrians crossing the lateral roads in the direcion of the main road (direction of walking is parallel to the main road).